# Why I can not do drag and drop in class Action perform Selenium 4?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I am using **chrome driver version 2.35** in 2023, **Why old chromedriver** version? That's because my project using **Chrome Extension Framework (CEF)** project.
[image]

1. Using maven project
2. IDE --> Intellij 2022.1.3
   my pom.xml file:

   ```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
   ```

3.My code :

```
 public static ChromeDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
    public static JavascriptExecutor jse;
    public static Actions builder;
    public static Action test;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException , Throwable {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8003");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        builder = new Actions(driver);

 WebElement fromElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='rounded-circle' and ./following-sibling::p[text()='Pendidikan']]"));
        WebElement fromElementPensiun = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='rounded-circle' and ./following-sibling::p[text()='Pensiun']]"));
        WebElement fromElement2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bag2']/div[3]"));
        WebElement toElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='bag1']"));
        Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(fromElementPensiun)
                .moveToElement(toElement)
                .release(toElement)
                .build();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        dragAndDrop.perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because our chromedriver.exe with **version 2.35**, so we need to downgrade the selenium - java also.
So, finally I using selenium-java version **3.141.59** :

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
   </dependency>
```